# If A and B are conditionally independent given C and B is independent of C. Prove that A and B are independent.

Tags: probability

If we have $C_{1}, C_{2}, C_{3}, .... C_{N}$ be a partition of the sample space S. Suppose we
know that A and B are conditionally independent given $C_{i}$, for all $i \in {1,2,...N}$ and
B is independent of all $C_{i}$ .

Prove that A and B are independent.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please begin by making an attempt to solve this problem.  Perhaps begin with the definition of conditional probability for independent random variables.